# Can you use an directional Antenna to sniff packets at a very long distance?

Tags: wireless, wifi

A normal wifi dongle can be configured in monitor mode to sniff out packets . What determine the range of distance the wifi dongle can sniff out? is it determined by what protocol the wifi dongle is configured to listen too? e.g. 802.11n which can transmit up to 250 m / 820 ft , does it also apply to listening for packets?

My second question is I want to extend the range of where I want to sniff packets , Would an directional antenna be useful for this purpose ? Can a directional listen to packets at a very long range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory yes, if your antenna is big enough. In practice there are limits. Consider the Voyager spacecraft. It's currenctly some 20 billion km (2.0 x 10^10 km) away from earth and has a 20 Watt radio transmitter (that's about 200 times your average 100mW WiFi signal). On Earth we can still pick up the signal but it requires a 38 meter dish antenna (the Voyager also has a dish antenna, making the signal highly directional).

So if you want to go long-distance, you need at least a dish antenna. See the picture of a [Cantenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantenna) on Wikipedia for something that looks like just what you need.

The same logic applies to your WiFi dongle; the only thing that determines the maximum receive distance is the power output of the transmitter and the sensitivity of the antenna and receiver. There is no limit inherent to 802.11n packets that says "stop after 250 meter"; radio waves continue infinitely far. The 250 meter limit is just the practical limit where current electronics are still able to transmit and receive reliably (Well, reliably.... perhaps in the middle of the Sahara with no other sources nearby. In a crowded urban environment you may not be able to have a reliable reception after 10 meters. But that's an entirely different question).

Comment: Note for **two-way** RF communication, there are practical limits of *distance*. Distance = time; there is more [propagation delay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_delay) incurred with increasing distance. At some distance *x*, the delay will be too great for these very fast signals, and their protocols will refuse to transceive. That's even if large directional antennas are used. (It takes 4-24 minutes to send, and another 4-24 to receive data between Earth and the Mars rovers.) Because WiFi is so fast, two-way comms is inherently range-limited by the protocol and propagation delay.

Comment: @JoneJamson Depends on the distance... What are we talking about here? 500 meter? 10 km? 384399 km (= the Moon)? Note that for passive listening ("sniffing") the only limit is really how big your receiving antenna can be.

Comment: @JoneJamson Huh? Sorry, but what you do think "directional antenna" means? Exactly that! Just point it in the direction you want to listen to, and voilá. You should be able to use a simple 'cantenna' if your range is a few houses.

Comment: No, that is definetely not a directional antenna; it's only more efficient omnidirectional one. A directional antenna is a dish or [something like this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/LPDA-large.jpg).

Comment: @JvO Can u help me answer this Q http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/224585/can-i-increase-the-gain-of-a-wifi-dongle-by-attaching-an-external-yagi-antenna